# -notlike not working as expected in Powershell script

Tags: powershell

This Powershell script should iterate through all vms in Virtualbox and take a snapshot with a given name if there is none with this name.
But it takes always a snapshot ...

```
$snapshot = 'untouched'
$vms = VBoxManage list vms
$snapscomp= "*"+$snapshot+"*"


ForEach($machine in $vms)
{
  if ($snapshots -notlike $snapscomp)
  {
    $machinename = $machine.Split('{')[0]
    $len = $machinename.Length-1
    VBoxManage snapshot $machinename.Substring(0,$len) take $snapshot
  }
}
```

I hope someone has a suggestion what i did wrong.

Comment: What is $snapshots?

Comment: Based on the snippet provided it looks like $snapshots is never assigned a value

Comment: You left the 's' off of $snapshot.  Also missing $machine in comparison.

Comment: O dear, I accidentally deleted a line where I assign the Value for $snapshots, thanks a lot (shouldnt work overtime without coffee^^)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the `-match` operator where I can.

```
  if ($snapshots -notmatch $snapshot)
  {
    $machinename = $machine.Split('{')[0]
    $len = $machinename.Length-1
    VBoxManage snapshot $machinename.Substring(0,$len) take $snapshot
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).